# Can I stop two words from breaking onto separate lines and creating an orphan?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph that ends with a link that contains the two word phrase "Read More". I'd like these two words to always be displayed on the same line. Right now, if the "More" can't fit on the same line, it gets bumped to the next line by itself.

Is there any CSS that will stop "Read More" from breaking onto separate lines?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a `<nobr>` tag in HTML that will do this, but it's deprecated. **[This page](http://davidwalsh.name/nobr-css)** suggests using `white-space:nowrap` instead.

**[white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)** is defined in the CSS1 specification and should be supported by all major browers.

Comment: I wouldn't even mention the <nobr> tag.. just use `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: I think OP should at least know about `<nobr>` in the event that he would've discovered it later and thought it was cool to use. ;)

Comment: That would be like saying I can use `<dir>` or `<menu>` to produce `<ul>`

Answer (score 13):

You can also place the non-breaking space between the two words:

```
Read&nbsp;More
```

although arguably this muddies HTML with presentation matters.

Answer (score 6):

```
<a href='#' class="my-readmore-css-class">Read more</a>

.my-readmore-css-class { white-space:nowrap; } // it should be style for your "Read more"
```