# prevent breaking of word with space in html

Tags: html, utf-8, character

I'm looking for a character that looks like a space, but is part of a word. So that you can have a word like: `abc def` and doesn't break to a new line if it's a at the end of the containing div.

To be more clear:

`hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello abc defghijklmn`

I want `abd defghijklmn` to be always next to eachother (because it's a company name)

Comment: [Can I stop two words from breaking onto separate lines and creating an orphan?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532826/can-i-stop-two-words-from-breaking-onto-separate-lines-and-creating-an-orphan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `&nbsp;` for NonBreakableSpace.

Comment: really, is that all it takes to do this? I feel a bit stupid now, always thought this was the same as a space.

Comment: Yes it is simple as it... enjoy :)