# Avoid breaking line between two words when resizing

Tags: html, css, string, text, line-breaks

I have a string and I need it not to break two specific words in different lines. Example:

```
"Ask for it it when contracting until 2016/09/30 with T-2 Rate"
```

When I resize window and make it smaller there is a moment that it outputs:

```
"Ask for it it when contracting until 2016/09/30 with T-2 \n
Rate"
```

I would like `T-2 + Rate` to be always together. How to do it?

Comment: Can you post your code and tell us what you've already tried?

Comment: post your code please?

Comment: Why don't you use specific width for the sentence para, in smaller resotion. So that it will keep the specific words and after that it will break.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You use a *nonbreaking space*. The HTML entity for it is `&nbsp;`. You'll probably want a non-breaking hyphen (`&#8209;`) in `T-2` as well:

```
Ask for it it when contracting until 2016/09/30 with T&#8209;2&nbsp;Rate
```

Example:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("target");
var originalWidth = target.innerWidth || target.clientWidth;
var width = originalWidth;
tick();
function tick() {
  width = width < 10 ? originalWidth : (width - 10);
  target.style.width = width + "px";
  setTimeout(tick, 400);
}
```

```css
#target {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Ask for it it when contracting until 2016/09/30 with T&#8209;2&nbsp;Rate</div>
```

Comment: Can you dupehammer this question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532826/can-i-stop-two-words-from-breaking-onto-separate-lines-and-creating-an-orphan ?

Answer (score 9):

Just use `<span style="white-space: nowrap">` for nonbreaking parts, as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr) states.

```html
Ask for it it when contracting until 2016/09/30 with <span style="white-space: nowrap">T-2 Rate</span>
```