# Can i improve "json_encode" results readability with <br> tags?

Tags: php, json, encode

i was just echoing my statement results as JSON-Object. But the function json_encode() puts out everything into a single line like that:

```
{"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3"0":{"username":"Olli"},"1":{"username":"Heiner"},"2":{"username":"Rolf"},"success":true,"rowcount":3}
```

Now imagine a JSONobject with hundred of more entries.

Is there a way to add some `<br>` tags or tab stops to improve the readabilty? this should only be for test purposes not for further parsing.

Comment: Why not json_decode it instead?

Comment: @tilz0R: ...and blow up the other end trying to consume the JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag.

```
echo json_encode([[[[[[['a'=>'b']]]]]]],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Outputs :

```
[
    [
        [
            [
                [
                    [
                        {
                            "a": "b"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Ref : http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: Please don't answer *obvious* duplicates. Find the dupetarget and vote to close instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder with all due respect, sir, I suspect you haven't earned 570k rep by never doing it yourself (ex : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611979/avoid-breaking-line-between-two-words-when-resizing/39612020#39612020). Consider that a lot of answers, such as this one, have to be written _very_ quickly nowadays. It's really easy to overlook checking for duplicates.